# Check radio button with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 radio buttons for gender.

```
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="Female" ng-model="$parent.gender" />Female
<input type="radio" name="answer" value="Male" ng-model="$parent.gender" />Male
```

I want to show a pre-selected form. I have the answers in an array in controller like this:

```
$scope.answers={gender:"Female"};
```

For this example, how can I set Female radio button based on answers object? Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you have `$parent` on there? What's the context? Are you in a ng-repeat?

Comment: I forgot to mention, I am using ng-include to show a html template and these were in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your `gender` variable that you declared as the model:

```
ng-model="$parent.gender"
```

So, set `$scope.gender = "Female"` to select that radio.

Answer (score 2):

### You need to remove the $parent

from the ng-model and come up with the genders scope variable. Here is the **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/snmkp91n/)**

and code snippet:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app>
    <div ng-controller="test">
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Female" ng-model="answers.gender" />Female
       <input type="radio" name="answer" value="Male" ng-model="answers.gender" />Male
     </div>
</div>
```

**CONTROLLER:**

```
function test($scope){
    $scope.answers={gender:"Female"};
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### You didn't need $parent

If you're not in a child scope, (ala ng-repeat), you don't need the $parent:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.answers = { gender: 'Female' };
});
```

HTML

```
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <input type="radio" value="Female" ng-model="answers.gender"/>
  <input type="radio" value="Male" ng-model="answers.gender"/>
</div>
```

### When to use $parent

Given your example shows `ng-model="$parent.gender"`, it looks like you think you need to get gender from the parent scope, this is only really necessary in an ng-repeat, which creates a child scope. You might find this when you create a list of radio buttons with a repeater:

JS:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.radioItems = ['Male', 'Female', 'Other'];

  $scope.answers = {
    gender: 'Female',
  };
});
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-repeat="radioItem in radioItems">
  <input type="radio" value="radioItem" ng-model="$parent.answers.gender"/>
</div>
```

#### EDIT: More detailed explanation of what's going on.